# Proof by pumping lemma

Tags: induction, automata

Let's say that we have to prove that $L = \{ww^Rv |w,v\in \Sigma^*\}$ is irregular.

I would take a string such that $w = baba^m$ and $w^R=a^mbab$ and $v = a$

and then I would pump divide $w$ into $xy, x = bab$ and $y = a$

According to the pigeonhole principle, because $a^m$ size can be infinite and the number of state is equal to the number of transitions - $1$, there must be a loop for y. if $|y|$ is greater than 1 then $w^R$ is not the reverse of $w$, thus we've proven the language is not regular.

Questions:

Is this correct?
It won't work for $w = baba$ and $w^R = abab$, right?

Comment: When applying the pumping lemma, you cannot choose $x,y,z$. You have to bring an argument that works for any choice of $x,y,z$ that can be chosen under the restrictions of the lemma (i.e., $|xy|\le p$, etc.).

Comment: what do you mean? what is p? p is the half of the length of w, right? any other restrictions?

Comment: $p$ is the pumping length. See the statement of the lemma here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Formal_statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better you don't succeed: the language *is* regular. Any string can be written $x = \epsilon \epsilon^R x$.